# Static files in django 2.2 vs static files in django 1.7

Tags: file, static

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlG5r.png)''https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/add-static-files/?trim=yes ''
I have been trying to do this project but with using latest django and python till now i was doing good but how to i employ this static thing with the newer version of django i keep on getting errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS6V7.jpg)

That's the error i got ( see the image)

Include an Image of the portion of settings.py file ( after line 125)

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code or error messages, instead copy and paste your code and error message into your post. This makes it easier for people to quickly help you. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Check out line 129 of your settings.py , you haven't closed the bracket of STATICFILES_DIRS . That's why you got an EOF Error.